# how to implement group chat by asmack

Tags: android, asmack

I use muc of asmack to create a room for group chat，but when I am offline，I will leave the room and others can't see me in the room.So the next time I have to join the room again. How to solve this problem?Give me some suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there could you be more specific on what you trying to achieve? It is normal when you offline you are leaving the room. For my case, I use openfire as my xmpp server when i joined a room i save the room data in database then once when i am online back i join back to the room and add message listener based on the info in database. Openfire will send you back the chat history once you join the room. This is feature can be change at Openfire console. Hope this help you =)

Comment: Thanks a lot！ That is the way what I implement this feature now.I just want to Know if there is another way to make it easier.

Comment: Welcome! This is the easiest way I know of so far.

Comment: If I run my app in a phone and join a room,then how the get the room data when I run the app in another phone.It there any way to save the data in the server?

Comment: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#MultiUserChat(org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection, java.lang.String)

The link is the javadoc for MultiUserChat class which allow you get certain info about the room. I am not sure what kind of data you intend to save to server, could you be more specific on it? and are you using openfire as well?

Comment: Yes,I use openfire as well.The room data I meant is all the rooms that a use have joined and the members in it.If I just save it in database,I will lose it if I login in in another phone,I have no way to achieve it.

Comment: You could change your room setting to persistent at openfire then use smack "DiscussionHistory" to retrieve the chat history from openfire. By setting the room to persistent you could keep the room data and could join back anytime. Hope this help you =)